# Filtering based on column with value in next row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a question on hot to filter values based on 2 columns but values not in the same row

like this

i want to filter if value from column A is the same of column B but in second row

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Heat | Light | Item 124 |
| Light | Heat | Item 124 |

etc
as it is large data set for multiple services provided in the same visit i want to reach combination of services provided together

Thanks

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Heat | Light | Item 124 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `filter(df, lag(A) == B)`

Comment: Thanks  It works only if only 2 observations found but condition is comlicated as not all cases are the same, some contains 4 or 10 services so order ranking is difficult

Answer (score -3):

Check this as an example [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6iey.png)

Check this as an example if more than 2 services requested this will be shown , and arranging them is very difficult

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).